# A Generic NHibernate wrapper with transactionality

Tags: c#

My team and I wrote the following Nhibernate wrapper which gives generic retrieval and save/update functions and a possibility to send a function as a paramater which may contain several save/update calls which will be committed or rollback transactionally:

```
public class DB
    {
        private const string sessionKey = "NHibernate.Db";
        private static bool keepSessionOpen = false;

        [ThreadStatic]
        private static ISession threadStaticSession = null;
        private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

        static DB()
        {
            sessionFactory = new SessionFactoryManager().CreateSessionFactory();
        }

        public static Boolean TransactionalMethod(Func<Boolean> transactionalMethod)
        {
            ITransaction transaction = null;
            Boolean hasActiveTranaction = Session.Transaction.IsActive;

            try
            {
                if (hasActiveTranaction == false)
                    transaction = Session.BeginTransaction();

                if (!transactionalMethod())
                {
                    if (hasActiveTranaction == false)
                        transaction.Rollback();
                    return false;
                }

                if (hasActiveTranaction == false)
                    transaction.Commit();

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                if (hasActiveTranaction == false)
                    transaction.Rollback();
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static ISession Session
        {
            get
            {
                ISession localSession;
                if (HttpContext.Current == null)
                {
                    if (threadStaticSession == null)
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine(" session==null");
                        threadStaticSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Starting static session");
                    }
                    Trace.WriteLine(" session!=null");
                    localSession = threadStaticSession;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(sessionKey))
                    {
                        localSession = (ISession)HttpContext.Current.Items[sessionKey];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        localSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Starting Http session");
                        HttpContext.Current.Items[sessionKey] = localSession;
                        keepSessionOpen = true;
                    }
                }
                return localSession;
            }
        }

        public static IList<T> Get<T>() where T : class
        {
            return Session.QueryOver<T>().List();
        }

        public static IList<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> filter) where T : class
        {
            return Session.QueryOver<T>().Where(filter).List();
        }

        public static Boolean MultipleSave<T>(IList<T> items) where T : class
        {
            return TransactionalMethod(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (T item in items)
                    {
                        Session.SaveOrUpdate(item);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

        public static Boolean Save<T>(T item) where T : class
        {
            return MultipleSave<T>(new List<T>() { item });
        }
    }
```

I may Call it like this:

```
Boolean transactionSucceeded = DB.TransactionalMethod(() =>
            {
                if (!DB.Save<Card>(newCardSession) || !DB.Save<Card>(oldCardSession))
                    return false;
                return true;
            });
```

if I want the 2 saves to be executed as 1 transaction.

Is this ok? We would be glad to hear about points for improvements.

Comment: Why do this instead of the standard way?  This seems unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 2):

- If a method returns false it is a failure, it also is failure if it throws. If you had (could?) stick with exceptions only:

  try { /* do sthg*/ return true;  } catch (Exception) { return false; }

constructs would be unnecessary. You already have two: in `MultipleSave` and `TransactionalMethod`. You also only need to call `MultipleSave` from `Save` in order to wrap it in the try-catch construct above.

If you stick with `Exception`s :

```
DB.TransactionalMethod(() =>
            {
                if (!DB.Save<Card>(newCardSession) || !DB.Save<Card>(oldCardSession))
                    return false;
                return true;
            });
```

becomes:

```
DB.TransactionalMethod(() =>
            {
                DB.Save<Card>(newCardSession);
                DB.Save<Card>(oldCardSession));
            });
```

- Also   `catch (Exception) { return false; }` squashes exceptions. You would want to log exceptions in order to diagnose why a command has failed. Did NHibernate generate invalid SQL, were your schemas invalid, did db die, was network connection lost?
- `ISessionFactory`, `ISession`, `ITransaction` all implement `IDisposable`; if you do not use them in a `using` block, you will probably leak resources.

Answer (score 0):

### [ThreadStatic] - DO NOT use in threadpool environment (like ASP.NET)

When the threads' lifetime isn't managed by us do not use ThreadStatic variables becouse the threads will be reused after every request (in ASP.NET) and we can accidently share variables and their status across multiple threads!